# Why do we need a Runnable to start threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, interface, runnable

Why we need to pass the runnable instance while creating the threads using the `Runnable` interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason we need to pass the runnable object to the thread object's constructor is that the thread must have some way to get to the `run()` method we want the thread to execute.

Take an e.g

```
public class CustomApplet extends Applet {
          public void init() {
                Runnable ot = new OurClass();
                Thread th = new Thread(ot);
                th.start();
         }
   }
```

Since we are no longer
overriding the `run()` method of the Thread class, the default `run()` method of the Thread class is
executed; this default `run()` method looks like this

```
public void run() {
         if (ot!= null) {
                    ot.run();
                   }
              }
```

Hence, `ot` is the runnable object we passed to the thread's constructor. So the thread begins execution with the `run()` method of the Thread class, which immediately calls the `run()` method of our runnable object.

Comment: Does the thread class implements the runnable interface automatically ?

Answer (score 5):

What do you want the new thread to do? You probably want it to execute some code. But what code must it run? You can't just put code in a thread. And Java does not have function pointers. A little trick to solve that problem is to use a object that implements a function. That function is `run`. So, the object must have a `run` method. That is what the Runnable interface does, assure it has a run method. Thus, if we give a Runnable object, the thread knows what to do!